# Firefox warns that "text/html is not a valid JavaScript MIME type" for a 404 script

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I chrome I get `404 not found` for the cached file but in mozila it is :

> The script from “https://sqa.micro-logic.ca/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/js/autoptimize_c25390e0b7b5140a1757c102b959bd63.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.

In both browser this error prevents my others scripts to be loaded and breaks my whole page. What is the second one ( mozila ) means? I didn't found a way to fix it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're trying to load a script that doesn't exist at the specified URL. The server returns an error page instead, so the script is not loaded.

Firefox additionally warns you that it received an HTML page (the error page) instead of the script. This should not affect other scripts on the page (unless they depend on the script that failed to load).

You should fix the URL, so that it returns the correct script.